# After JQuery on() is called, embed JavaScript stops running

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've tried this several different ways, at one point I had the `.on` call isolated to one line of code, and put `console.write()` messages before and after, the write messages don't fire after the `on()` is called. Scripts after this script's `</script>` tag work fine.

JavaScript is 1.2. Maybe it's too old?

```
$("body").on("change", ".media_frm", function(e)
{

    if(e.target.value.length == 0) return true; //if blank or undefined, it's okay
    var filename = e.target.value.match(/([^<\>\:\"\/\\\|\?\*])+$/i)[0]; //get rid of erroneous filepath
    var filetype = filename.match(/[^.]+$/i)[0]; //get extension after '.'
    if($.inArray(filetype, allowedExtensions) === -1)
    {
       alert("Invalid File Type: " + filename); 
        e.target.value = "";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    
});
```

Like I said, I've also set the above to a function, and just called `on()` on the element directly, like:

```
$(elem).on("change", verifyFunction);
```

and everything after this line will stop running, just like how everything stops running with the above block of code.

Comment: do you mean jQuery version is 1.2? If so it doesn't support `on()`. Not even `live()` was available that far back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery 1.6 does not support .on(). I have to use .bind().

```
$("body").bind("change", ".media_frm", function(e)
{

    if(e.target.value.length == 0) return true; //if blank or undefined, it's okay
    var filename = e.target.value.match(/([^<\>\:\"\/\\\|\?\*])+$/i)[0]; //get rid of erroneous filepath
    var filetype = filename.match(/[^.]+$/i)[0]; //get extension after '.'
    if($.inArray(filetype, allowedExtensions) === -1)
    {
       alert("Invalid File Type: " + filename); 
        e.target.value = "";
        return false;
    }
    return true;

});
```